# Interpreting interaction effect between two categorical predictors using linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction

I have read other threads regarding this topic, however, I haven't come across a results table that looks similar to mine (below) so I am seeking some clarification. I am using MIXED (SPSS v25) to analyse the effects of two categorical conditions each with two levels (Study A & B; Group A & B) and a continuous DV. The model also includes a random intercept of participants. The results of the Type III table and Estimates of Fixed Effects are below.

I am seeking help on interpreting these results please;

(a) There is a sig interaction between the two conditions (Study*Group) and a non-significant fixed effect of Group. **Does this mean that the effect of Group on the DV is dependent (or varies?? based) on Study?**

b)  I understand that categorical variables are given a reference category (which is given a value of 0 in the estimates of fixed effects table). From my understanding the table indicates that the intercept for Study A is -.153 + .377 and for Group A -.153 + .22 **If this is correct, how do you interpret the interaction (StudyA*GroupA)?**

**And is there any way to calculate the estimate, t-statistic, sig, etc. for the conditions in the interaction** (i.e. StudyA*GroupB, StudyB*GroupA) which currently have zeros (minus the reference group) so that I can report the relationship in my paper?

Thank you!!

[image: Type III & Estimates of fixed effects]

Comment: Apologies the Type III table should read in the first column going down: Intercept, Study, Group, Study*Group.